# DataRollBack with XtUnit in Nunit

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit

Today I ran XtUnit at a part of my unit testing framework to to rollback database changes created while running a test case. This is a skeleton of how I have used it. The Test case ran successfully but the database state changed as a result.

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using TeamAgile.ApplicationBlocks.Interception;
using TeamAgile.ApplicationBlocks.Interception.UnitTestExtensions;

namespace NameSpace.UnitTest
{
  [TestFixture]
  public class Test : InterceptableObject
  {
    [Test]
    [DataRollBack]
    public void CreateTest()
    {
```

I use Nhibernate with Mysql. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your test fixture needs to extend `ExtensibleFixture`, not `InterceptableObject`.  In the XtUnit source, `ExtensibleFixture` itself inherits from `InterceptableObject`.  The comments in ExtensibleFixture.cs state:

> This is the base class for all the test fixtures you will 
>   have in your project. You MUST inherit from this in order 
>   for the custom attributes to work. No other special action is needed.

Comment: if i use ExtensibleFixture the unittestcase is not getting loaded to run in Nunit. What will be the problem? i have win 7 o.s

Answer (score 0):

Database and your program must be run under WindowsXP SP2 oder Server 2003.